# How to make responsive Dialog from PyQt so that Contents will fit while resizing size

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have simple dialog with one Line Edit  and one Push Button widgets. After running applciation and while resizing the dialog
size these widgets(LineEdit and PushButton) does not fit to the dialog.How can i make these item responsive while resizing the
dialog box.

```
class Ui_ZValue(object):
    def setupUi(self, ZValue):
        ZValue.setObjectName("ZValue")
        ZValue.resize(400, 300)
        ZValue.setModal(False)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(ZValue)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 70, 131, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ZValue)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 150, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(ZValue)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ZValue)

    def retranslateUi(self, ZValue):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ZValue.setWindowTitle(_translate("ZValue", "Copy Z Cordinate"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("ZValue", "Cofirm"))


import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication
from  makebeautiful import *
class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_ZValue()
        self.ui.setupUi(self）
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dispmessage)
        self.show()
    def dispmessage(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText("clicked")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)

    w=MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: maybe you should use some layout manager like VBoxLayout, HBoxLayout instead of `setGeometry`. Layout managers usually resize widgets in window when you resize window.

Comment: [Layout management in PyQt5](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/)

Comment: As Furas points out the best thing is to use layouts, I would like to give you an answer but your description is not clear, what is responsive is very subjective.

Comment: @eyllanesc and furas  thanks for reply. Responsive meaning that the inner widget items sizes should be resizable when the main dialog is resized.When using BoxLayouts they are fixed in the main dialog and could not resize according to changed dialog size .

Comment: @Devenepali But be more precise, for example if the width is doubled, what should happen with the geometry (x, y, width, height) of the QPushButton ?, the same if the height is also doubled

Comment: @eyllanesc though i am not very experienced with PyQt i wanted to make inner widget (like QPushButton will be  get double  size(in height and width) if main dialog size is also doubled(height and width) .Also,if width of  main Dialog is increase  with double size then QPushButton's width only should be increased.

Comment: By default Qt does not implement it because desktop applications do not behave this way, unlike web applications because they must run on different screens. If you want to implement that behavior then you must track the dialog size change and then set a new geometry. In your comment you explained the change in size, but how should the position of the widget behave? What should happen between the space between QPushButton and QLineEdit? the logic is not generic, it will depend on what exactly you want. I have never seen a desktop application that behaves like this.